# Get Top N items from mapper output - Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

My Mapper task returns me following output:

```
2   c
2   g
3   a
3   b
6   r
```

I have written reducer code and keycomparator that produces the correct output but how do I get Top 3 out (top N by count) of Mapper Output:

```
public static class WLReducer2 extends
        Reducer<IntWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (Text x : values) {
            context.write(new Text(x), key);
        }

    };

}

public static class KeyComparator extends WritableComparator {
    protected KeyComparator() {
        super(IntWritable.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Logger.error("--------------------------> writing Keycompare data = ----------->");
        IntWritable ip1 = (IntWritable) w1;
        IntWritable ip2 = (IntWritable) w2;
        int cmp = -1 * ip1.compareTo(ip2);

        return cmp;
    }
}
```

This is the reducer output:

```
r   6
b   3
a   3
g   2
c   2
```

The expected output from reducer is  top 3 by count which is:

```
r   6
b   3
a   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restrict your output from reducer. Something like this.

```
public static class WLReducer2 extends
        Reducer<IntWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    int count=0;
    @Override
    protected void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (Text x : values) {
            if (count > 3)
            context.write(new Text(x), key);
            count++;
        }

    };
}
```

Set number of reducers to 1. `job.setNumReduceTasks(1)`.

Comment: Thanks , the solution did work for me. Setting number of reducers to 1 is not going to create performance issue ?

Comment: We are not going to write much to the output and since we need to compute top N elements we have to bring the data to single reducer to compute it.  You could use a combiner(depending on the data set) that would reduce some performance bottleneck.

Comment: Just take into account the count statement should be if (count < 3), otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If your Top-N elements could be stored in memory, you could use a TreeMap to store the Top-N elements and if your process could be aggregated using only **one reducer**.

1. Instantiate a instance variable TreeMap in the **setup()** method of your reducer.
2. Inside your **reducer()** method you should aggregate all the values for the keygroup and then compare the result with the first (lowest) key in the Tree, `map.firstKey()`. If your current value is bigger than the lowest value in the Tree then insert the current value into the treemap, `map.put(value, Item)` and then delete the lowest value from the Tree `map.remove(value)`.
3. In the reducer's **cleanup()** method, write to the output all the TreeMap's elements in the required order.

**Note:** The **value** to compare your records must be the **key** in your TreeMap. And the **value** of your TreeMap should be the description, tag, letter, etc; related with the **number**.